The refresh token call is not being triggered when the network disconnects and then reconnects using angular-oauth2-oidc
I am using angular-oauth2-oidc v15.0.1 in my Angular project to authenticate my application with the Identity Server. We have implemented a refresh token that is triggered just before the token expires. While everything generally works well, I encounter an issue when the network disconnects during a refresh token call, resulting in an "ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED" error. After this error, the refresh token call does not retry.
I am planning to put the retry after once the network reconnects. Could you please suggest a smooth way to handle this situation?
